# Building Virtual Host on Mac - Is not working

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm trying to build an Virtual Host on my Mac OS, but it's not working.

The apache2/error_log  recorded the follow message

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Fri May 03 15:34:57 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 03 15:34:57 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 03 15:34:58 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 03 15:35:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
[Fri May 03 15:35:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
```

And the browser return this....

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch Server at dev.myhost.test Port 80
```

I've stayed a long time trying to fix this. But I didn't succeed...

Here ir my /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/smileflame"
    ServerName dev.smileflame.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/teste"
    ServerName dev.myhost.test
</VirtualHost>
```

The next is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1  dev.myhost.test
```

I would like this vhost redirect to my index.php... But this is not happening...
Anybody know why????

Comment: What URL are you using in the browser to request the page?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make two `/etc/hosts` entries with the same IP. Put the aliases on the same line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost dev.myhost.test
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```